# Display Error When DB has no entry (Ruby on Rails 4.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this application that will display Zip code eligibility. I got the search function working. It returns a zip code and the message when it finds an eligible zip code.

But I want to display an error when it can't find an entry. Right now it just displays the same search page with no info.

This is my view

```
<h1>
  Pick-up/Delivery Eligibility
</h1>
<h3>
Based on U.S. Zipcode, Canadian Postal Code
</h3>
<p class="el">
  To find out if you qualify for 4over&#146;s local delivery service,
  please enter your <nobr>U.S. 5 digit zip code, or</nobr> your 
  <nobr>Canadian 6 character Postal Code,</nobr> then click submit.

<%= form_tag zips_path, :method => "get" do %>
  <p><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %> | <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></p>
<% end %>

<!--

<h4>Current Eligible Zip Codes</h4>

<% @zips.each do |zip| %>
  <p><%= link_to zip.zip, zip %>|<%= zip.state %> <%= link_to "Edit", edit_zip_path(zip) %> | <%= link_to "Delete", zip, :confirm => "Are you Sure?", :method => :delete %> </p>
  <hr />
<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "Add a New Zip", new_zip_path %></p>

-->

<% @zips.each do |zip| %>
  <hr />
  <p>
    Your zipcode <span style="background-color:yellow"><tt><b><%= zip.zip %></b></tt></span> is eligible for local delivery, in the following zone(s):
     <span style="background-color:yellow"><tt><b><%= zip.state %></b></tt></span>
     <p class=el>
    Please fill out the form at this link: <%= link_to "Application Form", "http://tools.4over.com/feedel.pdf" %>
    <p class="el">
    The following terms and conditions apply: <p class="if">We do not guarantee delivery time and date; we do our best to stay within the
    scheduled delivery period, but in case of any emergency, extra work
    load, or unforeseen circumstances deliveries might be postponed to the
    following day or cancelled.
    <p class="if">4over, Inc. will not be responsible for any
    problem such as loss of business/customers that may be caused by late
    delivery or NO delivery.
    <p class="if">This is a courtesy service and we reserve
    the right to refuse service to anyone. We reserve the right to
    alter a specific zone/route or cancel any zone/route.
    We do not guarantee a press time to print your jobs to match
    with your delivery schedule.
</p>
<% end %>
```

This is my model file

```
class Zip < ActiveRecord::Base
  ###
  # Validations below
  ###
  validates :zip, :state, :presence => true
  validates :zip, :length => { :minimum => 5, :maximum => 6 }
  validates :state, :length => { :minimum => 2, :maximum => 3 }
  validates :zip, :uniqueness => true
  ##
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['zip LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
end
```

This is my action in my controller file

```
class ZipsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @zips = Zip.search(params[:search])
  end
...
end
```

What I want to do is send a flash message from the action. (a ":notice => "Zip code not eligible") but I'm not sure what to test for

I tried

```
if not @zips.search
  redirect_to zips_path, :notice => "Zipcode is not eligible"
end
```

But that didn't work. Is there something that I can test for to return the flash message?

Here is my log

```
Started GET "/zips?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=91702" for 10.7.2.31 at 2013-08-05 17:07:52 -0700
Processing by ZipsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"91702"}
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #find(:all) is deprecated. Please call #all directly instead. You have also used finder options. These are also deprecated. Please build a scope instead of using finder options. (called from search at /var/www/html/localdel/app/models/zip.rb:37)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).to_a`). (called from search at /var/www/html/localdel/app/models/zip.rb:37)
  Zip Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "zips".* FROM "zips" WHERE (zip LIKE '%91702%')
  Rendered zips/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 4.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 10.7.2.31 at 2013-08-05 17:07:52 -0700
```

I'm a newbie on both Ruby and Rails; so any help would be great!

Thanks!

P.S

I'm using Ruby 1.9.x and Rails 4.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
if not @zips.search
    redirect_to zips_path, :notice => "Zipcode is not eligible"
end
```

with this:

```
if @zips.search.empty?
    redirect_to zips_path, :notice => "Zipcode is not eligible"
end
```

An empty array ([]) resolves to "true" in Ruby. Another thing you could use if you're in Rails is .blank?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! What worked for me was using the .blank? - this gave me the behavior I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
if @zips.empty
  redirect_to zips_path, :notice => "Zipcode is not eligible"
end
```